# sql select using between and like

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select data from a table using a range of numbers . In short i want to select the paths where there a number in a range of 6 to 9

```
$sql = "select * from users where path_name like  between '%6%' and '%9%' ";
```

But nothing is being returned.

Anyone with a better way to do this?

Comment: Assuming it is MySQL use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Provide more detail of what you are actually trying to achieve. Between will not function how you want it to on string values.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And please [edit] your question and add the table definition as a `create table` statement, [no screenshots please](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for guys

`$sql1 = "select * from users where path_name REGEXP '[6-9]'";`
Reference
[Regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

[Example of regular expression in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612580/mysql-like-with-range-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `like`

If you want to return all numbers between `6` and `9`:

```
$sql = "select * from users where path_name between 6 and 9";
```

Comment: the pathname has values such as  download5, download6, download7, download8, download9, download10 . I want select pathname based on numbers 6 to 8.. And thats why I want to use `like`.

Answer (score 0):

Since path_name is number you should use condition statements. Consider usage of `where path_name >= 6 and path_name <= 9` or simpler with 5 and 10 with sharp conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE SUBSTR(PATH_NAME, 4, len(PATH_NAME)-4) BETWEEN 6 and 9
```

I suppose your path_name values are like 'axr6b'

Comment: Remember the values 6 to nine are dummy.. I real time i will replace them with dynamic variables

Comment: http://forgetcode.com/Teradata/1619-SUBSTR  Incase you want to know more about SUBSTR()

Answer (score 0):

If it is SQL Server, `Like` can be used by range match

```
declare @users table (path_name varchar(10)) 
insert @users values
     ('download1'), ('download3'), ('download5'), ('download6'), 
     ('download7'), ('download9'), ('download10')

select * from @users where path_name like '%[6-9]%'
```

Comment: That LIKE is a product specific extension... (And no dbms tagged.)

Comment: @jarlh Thanks, added the dbms type in the answer

Comment: @Eric that's exactly what I wanted, But how can I do that in mysql?